# Disable GUI and Go to Command Line Terminal

Tags: command-line, gui

I am trying to temporarily disable the GUI in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148321/how-do-i-stop-gui) [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46203/disable-x-server-and-gnome-temporarily) and type `sudo stop lightdm` it does disable to the GUI, but all that is left is a black screen without a terminal. What I would like to be able to do is turn the GUI off, run a script from the terminal, and then turn the GUI back on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Turn the gui off by pressing ctrl+alt+F1.
- Run the script from the virtual console.
- Then run `sudo service lightdm restart` command to get back gui on.